# RubyPython imports

Tags: python, ruby, rubypython

I'm fairly new to both python and ruby.

I've created a python script that imports it's dependencies like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/share/anki")
from anki import Collection
from anki.importing import TextImporter
```

How do I achieve the same functionality in RubyPython? Among other things, I've tried:

```
RubyPython.start

sys = RubyPython.import("sys")
sys.path.append("/usr/share/anki")
Collection = RubyPython.import("anki.Collection")
TextImporter = RubyPython.import("anki.importing.TextImporter")

RubyPython.stop
```

Which gives me an error: `` `import': AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv' (RubyPython::PythonError) `` for the line for anki.Collection import.

I've also tried something like this:

```
RubyPython.start

sys = RubyPython.import("sys")
sys.path.append("/usr/share/anki/anki")
Collection = RubyPython.import("collection")
TextImporter = RubyPython.import("anki.importing.TextImporter")

RubyPython.stop
```

Which gives me an error: `` `import': ImportError: No module named anki.lang (RubyPython::PythonError) `` for the line for collection import. You can see from [the source code for anki](https://github.com/dae/anki/blob/master/anki/collection.py) that this is the first thing imported in the collection.py file.

Comment: Python interpreter is embedded, thus it makes sense that some process-specific bits, e.g. `sys.argv` are not available. Your first attempt seems pretty decent, question is, what uses `argv`? is it used by your code?

Comment: Nope. I'm not using `argv` explicitly.

Comment: Answer updated with full trace to `sys.argv` usage at import time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python interpreter is embedded, thus it makes sense that some process-specific bits, e.g. `sys.argv` are not available.

Here's a quick test without ruby:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: del sys.argv

In [3]: sys.path.append("anki")

In [6]: import anki.Collection
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ff326ec5c6ff> in <module>()
----> 1 import anki.Collection

/dima/anki/anki/__init__.py in <module>()
     32 
     33 version="2.0.16" # build scripts grep this line, so preserve formatting
---> 34 from anki.storage import Collection
     35 __all__ = ["Collection"]

/dima/anki/anki/storage.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 import os, copy, re
----> 6 from anki.lang import _
      7 from anki.utils import intTime, json
      8 from anki.db import DB

/dima/anki/anki/lang.py in <module>()
    103 
    104 if not currentTranslation:
--> 105     setLang("en_US", local=False)

/dima/anki/anki/lang.py in setLang(lang, local)
     82 def setLang(lang, local=True):
     83     trans = gettext.translation(
---> 84         'anki', langDir(), languages=[lang], fallback=True)
     85     if local:
     86         threadLocal.currentLang = lang

/dima/anki/anki/lang.py in langDir()
     75         os.path.abspath(__file__)), "locale")
     76     if not os.path.isdir(dir):
---> 77         dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "locale")
     78     if not os.path.isdir(dir):
     79         dir = "/usr/share/anki/locale"

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

Ideally your code should not rely on `sys.argv`, consider for example if your module is used by another project, you can make no assumption about what ends up in `sys.argv`.

- If you want your code/resource directory, use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` instead(*)
- if you really need `sys.argv`, inject fake array into `sys` before you import your modules.

(*)Keep in mind that Python code can also be shipped as a zip, in which case you don't even have a directory in the traditional sense.

Comment: I'm not responsible for the Anki code; I'm simply using it. But tracing down the issue has helped me enough. Thanks.

Comment: then you can either inject fake `sys.argv` or ask RubyPython developers to call `PySys_SetArgvEx()` in RubyPython init. Perhaps optionally, as it's not clear if command line arguments should be inherited.

Comment: @KDawG, because it doesn't let me award the bounty yet. Need to wait at least 24h since I offered it.